# What is the best approach when upgrading Laravel project to 9.0 from 6.0?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-9

When upgrading from laravel 6 to 9 is it better to go 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 or one can safely jump from 6 to 9?

Comment: If no easy answer what should one consider if deciding to go 6 -> 9?

Comment: That's a big jump, and there's no easy, manual way to do it directly from `6.x` -> `9.x`... But, Laravel includes an "Upgrade Guide" for each version: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade and https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade. (`6.x` -> `7.x`, `7.x` -> `8.x` and finally `8.x` -> `9.x`). Or, there are tools like Laravel Shift: https://laravelshift.com/, but they're not free.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean *which upgrade guides to follow* or how to *technically* upgrade?

You need to make sure you handle all changes introduced in 7, 8 and 9, so you'd need to read every upgrade guide separately.

But technically you can jump from 6 to 9.

I personally prefer to start a fresh project and then apply my codebase to it, gradually. That way you end up having a new boilerplate as well, as sometimes new Laravel versions introduce new useful files in the project root.